# Random selection from a list with more selections than listed items

Tags: groovy

I am new to Groovy, so I apologize if this is kind of a noob question.

I have a list of items 50 long and they are all identified by an ID number from 1-50. I want to be able to select from this list at random *more times than I have items in the list* (122 right now, but potentially many more times than that). The current code I have tried is:

```
list.shuffle.next(122).each {}
```

The problem I'm coming across is that actions created inside the brackets will only iterate the number of times as I have numbers in the list (50). Rather than doing the action 50 times, then 50 times again, then 22 times (in which each item would be selected at least twice and no more than 3 times), I would prefer a truly random method of selection.

**What is a better way of writing this?**

Thank you!

Comment: Try creating an example of what you've already attempted at https://groovy-playground.appspot.com/ and sharing it here.

Answer (score 4):

## [**Here's a groovy way to do it.**](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c024f7d1de4bcb694d9c52dd4120cd0b)

```
// list of integers 1 to 50
def list = 1..50

// where you're going to store your picks from
def selection = []

// what you're going to pick
def random = new Random()

// 0 to 121 is 122 items
(0..121).each {
    // pick from the list at random
    selection << list[ random.nextInt(list.size()) ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.util.Random` to pick random elements in a list:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>(); //fill this list with objects
List<Object> results = new ArrayList<>(); //results will be saved in here
Random rng = new Random(); //a new random number generator
int i = 0;
while (i++ < 100) {
  int randomIndex = rng.nextInt(list.size()); //random index in the list
  Object result = list.get(randomIndex);
  results.add(result);
}
```

At the end, there will be 100 results in `results`, randomly picked from `list`.

On a side note, this code will obviously not work for an empty list and throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give this a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Do you prefer the Java syntax?